# Picking two different images in the same view controller using imagePickerController with 1 button in Swift 2 & 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2

I am trying to select the images each with 1 button but it not displaying any images which I had selected.

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBAction func chooseImage1(sender: AnyObject) {
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
    println("Button capture")

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

@IBAction func chooseImage2(sender: AnyObject) {
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
    println("Button capture")


    imagePicker2.delegate = self
    imagePicker2.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker2.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    chooseImage1.image = pickedImage

let pickedImage2 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
chooseImage2.image = pickedImage2



dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I would like to be able to select two individual different photos on the imageView each. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` can only pick images one at a time. To do a multiple selection, you should use a well updated API like [this](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker).